# How to show coverage color on the code in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-coverage, eclemma

I run my application with coverage mode, but, a file don't have color on the code.
Is there a macro (or an other solution) to show color of coverage in Eclipse ?

Comment: Seems like whenever I rename a class, I have to restart Eclipse to get coverage to show.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question implies that you have the `EclEmma` installed in your `Eclipse`, otherwise I suppose that the coverage mode you mentioned would not be accessible. In case it's installed you should see the `EclEmma configuration` button near the `Run Configuration` button in the Eclipse toolbar. It looks like `Run` button, with a coloured bar at the right bottom corner [image]. Click it to see the drop-down list and choose `Coverage Configurations...`. You will see a dialog that looks like `Run Configurations` but it has an additional tab marked `Coverage`. Open it and check the only checkbox found there. 
[image]After it's checked, you can run your code in the coverage mode by pressing the `Coverage` button in the `Coverage Configurations` dialog or just by choosing the required configuration from the drop-down list of the `EclEmma` toolbar button.

Note that the coverage colors might be not seen in the editor if they are not properly set in the Eclipse preferences (`General->Editors->Text Editors->Annotations`, `Full Coverage`, `No Coverage` and `Partial Coverage`).

For more detail see the [EclEmma website](http://www.eclemma.org/).

Comment: In my case I had several packages selected under the coverage tab, so I checked only those that I needed and it worked.